# Configurar multer en typescript

Tags: nodejs, typescript, multer

//Hola gente, estoy configurando una res api para poder subir imágenes y me quede atascado en esto,

```
import multer from "multer";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import path from "path";
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

export class VerifyImages{

verifyPortada(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction){
    let storage =  multer.diskStorage({
        destination: `uploads/portada_images/${req.userId}/`,
        filename: (res, file, cb)=>{
            cb(null, uuidv4() + path.extname(file.originalname))
        }
    })
    return storage
  }
}

const verify = new VerifyImages()
const storage = verify.verifyPortada
export default multer({storage})
```

les cuento lo que hago acá, en esta clase tengo un meto que configura multer, lo que hago acá es generar una carpeta llamada `portada_images` mas el id del usuario, para tener un poco mas de orden, lo que me esta pasando es que necesito ingresar el `let storage` dentro de `multer({storage})` pero al hacerlo así, el `storage` dentro de multer me devuelve el siguiente error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

//Mi intención de hacer esta configuración, es que al exportar esta función desde la rutas quede de esta manera

```
import VerifyPort from './verifyPort';
this.router.post('/', verifyToken, VerifyPort.single('image'), this.establecerPortada)
```

de esta manera solo bastaría agregar el `.single('image')` y seguir con la siguiente funciona, muchas gracias por su atención, si necesitan mas datos con gusto se los daré

Comment: necesito ayuda por favor